# Using iOS device as headset

Tags: iphone, ios, bluetooth

Can I use an iOS device as a headset?

I have a Texas Instruments CC2564-BLUEBRIDGE module which are connected to a GSM module and all device functions as a phone.

I need to write an app for iOS devices which can connect via bluetooth to this "phone" and act as a headset.

I tried to do it through AVAudioSession, but it turns out only transmit sound in one direction, either from the iPhone microphone to the device or from the device to the dynamics of the iPhone.

How can I solve this problem, and can solve it at all?

Comment: Maybe by looking for a "streaming" sound (from your TI device) like approach...

Comment: I already try it, but it similar problem here, i need two streams. One from iPhone mic to device and second from device to iPhone speaker. And all I can find is only one direction stream at a time, not both.